# Passing data between two android apps using intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two separate android apps, AppA and AppB. I am trying to get AppA to launch AppB (which is a game app). After the user is done playing the game (AppB), it will send the game records back to AppA.

So, AppA is launching AppB correctly, but when user is done with playing the game (AppB), AppB crashes while sending the data back to AppA, and this error shows up:

> Process: com.joy.AppB, PID: 20265
>                                                                       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.joy.AppA/com.joy.AppA.views.activities.StartGameActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

AppA package name : com.joy.AppA

Activity class name : com.joy.AppA.views.activities.StartGameActivity

AppB package name : com.joy.AppB

Activity class name : com.joy.AppB.MainActivity

Here is what I've done so far:

AppA's StartGameActivity:

```
//To launch AppB game
Intent launchGameIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.joy.AppB");
startActivity(launchGameIntent);

//To retrieve game scores from AppB game
Intent intent = getIntent();
String[] gameRecords_array = intent.getStringArrayExtra("gameRecord");
```

AppA's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.joy.AppA">
.
.
.
<activity
        android:name="com.joy.AppA.views.activities.StartGameActivity"
        android:label="Start Game">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".views.activities.DashboardActivity" />
    </activity>
```

AppB's MainActivity:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.joy.AppA","com.joy.AppA.views.activities.StartGameActivity"));
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra("gameRecord", gameRecord_array);
startActivity(i);
```

AppB's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.joy.AppB" >

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

AppA's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.joy.AppA">
    .
    .
    .
    <activity
            android:name="com.joy.AppA.views.activities.StartGameActivity"
            android:label="Start Game">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.joy.AppA.views.activities.LAUNCH_IT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".views.activities.DashboardActivity" />

        </activity>
```

Then to send data to app a activity from app b, do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.joy.AppA.views.activities.LAUNCH_IT");
i.putExtra("gameRecord", gameRecord_array);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just like to ask if you know how I can get AppA to receive multiple string arrays from AppB? Currently AppB is sending multiple string arrays to AppA at one go, but AppA is only receiving the first string array from the chunk. Thanks!

Comment: @unintendedjoy, glad my answer was of help to you. If understand your comment question correctly, you want to send different arrays to the activity ?. You could do this:

`Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.joy.AppA.views.activities.LAUNCH_IT");
i.putExtra("gameRecordArray1", gameRecord_array);
i.putExtra("gameRecordArray2", gameRecord_array);
i.putExtra("gameRecordArray3", gameRecord_array);
i.putExtra("gameRecordArray4", gameRecord_array);
startActivity(i);`

Comment: Actually, I meant it like this, you can see from this question I posted: [Passing multiple string arrays between two apps using intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533566/passing-multiple-string-arrays-between-two-apps-using-intent?noredirect=1#comment72202953_42533566) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be useful:

**Content Provider and Content Resolver components**.

Content Resolver makes request to Content Provider, and the provider respond. This is similar to a communication between two different applications.

For example a client (Resolver) and a content manager(Provider).

This is an example tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm

Hope it helps!