# Communicate between two apps

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-intent

I am developing a unity android app and an android studio app to work. I want to open and close them using each other and to pass messages between them. How can I achieve this? Both apps are in one phone.

1. How to create a intent of the unity app in android studio?
2. How to invoke a method of unity app inside android studio app?
3. How to invoke a method of android studio app inside unity app?

I am completely new to android development. Even though there are similar questions, couldn't find a solution that worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Both apps should be installed on one phone and open each other?

Comment: in one phone and open each other

Comment: May be it can be helpful to get idea [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511715/passing-data-between-two-android-apps-using-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511715/passing-data-between-two-android-apps-using-intent).

Answer (score 0):

If both apps are installed on one phone and should interact you can use [Broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html)